# ReportLab: Flowable too large on page 1 in frame 'normal' of template 'First'

Tags: python, reportlab

I build PDF using ReportLab. My program has a `MyDocTemplate(SimpleDocTemplate)` class with two methods: `beforePage(self)` and `afterPage(self)` which add header and footer (as PNG image) on every page. There is also a `MyDocStyle` class which describe `ParagraphStyle`.

Main method looks like this:

```
TITLE = Paragraph(Title, MyDocStyle.h1)
TO = Paragraph(To, MyDocStyle.h2)
FROM = Paragraph(From, MyDocStyle.h2)
SUBJECT = Paragraph(Subject, MyDocStyle.h2)
LONG_PARAGRAPH = Paragraph(Text, MyDocStyle.h3)
...

Elements = [TITLE, TO, FROM, SUBJECT, LONG_PARAGRAPH, ...]
doc = MyDocTemplete('output.pdf', pagesize=A4, 
                     leftMargin=2*cm, rightMargin=2*cm,
                     topMargin=4*cm, bottomMargin=4*cm)
doc.build(Elements)
```

Data comes from CSV files and GUI. From time to time (depends on data length) I receive an error:

```
Flowable <Spacer at 0x2631120 frame=normal>...(1 x 5.66929133858) too large
on page 1 in frame 'normal'(469.88976378 x 603.118110236) of template 'First'
```

This exception stop my program. For short Paragraphs I set in `MyDocStyle` class `h2.keepWithNext = 1` however it's not perfect solution. ReportLab split correctly long paragraph if end of paragraph does not "coincide" with end of page (text area).

How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 7):

This error occurs when ReportLab try to split a Spacer over two pages. It seems that the only way to workaround this issue is wrap your Spacer into a KeepTogether element:

```
elements.append(KeepTogether(Spacer(width, height)))
```

Comment: For future readers: The full module path is: `reportlab.platypus.KeepTogether`

Comment: Quick update on [Moshe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/875832/moshe)'s comment, as of July 2021 (Reportlab Version 3.5.20) import is from `reportlab.platypus.flowables import KeepTogether`

Answer (score -3):

**Solved.** Don't use `Spacer` (e.g. `Spacer(1, 0.2*cm)`) as a separator for `Paragraph`. Instead, define `spaceBefore` and `spaceAfter` in `ParagraphStyle`, for example:

```
ParagraphStyle(name = 'Normal',
               fontName = "Verdana",
               fontSize = 11,
               leading = 15,
               alignment = TA_JUSTIFY,
               allowOrphans = 0,
               spaceBefore = 20,
               spaceAfter = 20,
               wordWrap = 1)
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue, and few tests show that Spacer does not seem to be the problem. Please dont make users afraid of using it, unless there is some other basis behind your hypothesis.